# Can static_cast be done from base class to derived class if derived class contains additional methods and members?

Tags: c++, static-cast

Suppose we have class A and B as follows:

```
class A
{
  private:
   int a;

  public:

   void seta(int a_)
    {
       a=a_;
    }
   int geta()
   {
    return a;
   }
  };

class B: public A
{
  private:
   int b;

  public:

   int getb()
     {
       return b;
     }

  void setb()
   {
     b=geta()+1;
   }

 };
```

and suppose that I make such code in the function:

```
A* a=new A();
a->seta(5);
B* b=static_cast<B*>(a);
b->setb();
cout<<b->getb()<<" and "<<b->geta()<<endl;
```

This code compiles and runs, but it confuses me why? If `a` is pointer to `A` class and during allocation only memory for `class A` members is reserved (at runtime), why after static cast it seems that this object is actually instance of `class B`. Is this safe operation?

Comment: I thought this was undefined behavior. And should your top line say "A and B"?

Comment: I thought as well. But it seems it works, and I don't know why?

Comment: If your code has undefined behaviour the compiler isn't required to tell you, and the resulting program may do anything at all - including seeming to work correctly. That doesn't mean it's a good idea to do it.

Comment: It is only safe to do `b = static_cast<B*>(a)` if `a` is known to actually be a `B`.  Otherwise, dereferencing `b` gives undefined behaviour .... and a compiler is not required to diagnose that.

Comment: @Peter: Doesn't the `static_cast` itself already cause UB, even if you do not ever dereference the result?

Comment: @Christian - it does.   But, practically, the manifestation of the undefined behaviour of a `static_cast` with most compilers is "nothing of note happens at that point".   It is subsequent dereferencing (which also has undefined behaviour) where any symptom is more likely to actually be observed.   Trying to explain that nuance to a novice is often an exercise in frustration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[expr.static.cast]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#11), emphasis mine:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv1* `B`”, where `B` is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv2* `D`”, where `D` is a class derived (Clause 10) from `B`, if *cv2* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv1*. If `B` is a virtual base class of `D` or a base class of a virtual base class of `D`, or if no valid standard conversion from “pointer to `D`” to “pointer to `B`” exists (4.11), the program is ill-formed. The null pointer value (4.11) is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type. If the prvalue of type “pointer to *cv1* `B`” points to a `B` that is actually a subobject of an object of type `D`, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type `D`. **Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

Answer (score 0):

This is not a safe thing to do.
The following code demonstrates why

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A 
{
private:
  int a;

public:  
  void seta(int a_) {
    a=a_;
    cout << "seta to: " << a << endl;
  }

  int geta() {
    return a;
  }
};

class B: public A
{
  private:
   int b;

  public:

  int getb() {
    return b;
  }

  void setb() {
    b=geta()+1;
    cout << "setb to: " << b << endl;
  }  
};

int main() {

  A as[2];

  A* a1=as;
  A* a2=&as[1];

  a1->seta(5);
  a2->seta(4);

  cout << "a1: "
       << a1->geta()
       << endl;

  cout << "a2: " 
       << a2->geta()
       << endl;

  B* b=static_cast<B*>(a1);

  b->setb();

  a2->seta(3);

  cout << "b->geta(): "
       << b->geta()
       <<" and b->getb(): "  
       << b->getb()
       << endl;

  size_t sizeofa(sizeof(A));
  cout << "sizeofa: "
       << sizeofa
       << endl;

  size_t sizeofb(sizeof(B));
  cout << "sizeofb: "
       << sizeofb
       << endl;

}
```

The output is

```
seta to: 5
seta to: 4
a1: 5
a2: 4
setb to: 6
seta to: 3
b->geta(): 5 and b->getb(): 3
sizeofa: 4
sizeofb: 8
```